# block executing before modal click

Tags: magento2, phtml, modal

I have a modal with 2 buttons that have a click function. Inside of each of these click functions is a block that's supposed to only be executed when clicked. However, the block seems to be executed before one of the buttons is clicked.

```
buttons: [
            {
                text: $.mage.__(`Don't Allow`),
                class: 'dontAllow',
                click: function(){
                    console.log(`I clicked Don't Allow`);
                    <?= $block->disableAdminUsage(); ?>
                    this.closeModal();
                },
            },
            {
                text: $.mage.__('Ok'),
                class: 'action',
                click: function(){
                    console.log("I clicked Ok");
                    <?= $block->enableAdminUsage(); ?>
                    this.closeModal();
                },
            }
        ],
```

Comment: Yes, because you use those in php. So when echoed it executed. What you return from enableAdminUsage and disableAdminUsage?

Comment: @SohelRana enableAdminUsage and disableAdminUsage simply edits the value and saves it. 

 $configModel = $this->configFactory->create();
 $configModel->setDataByPath('path', 0);
 $configModel->save();

Comment: wrong. you should move this to controller and call ajax on click event.